# Xamarin Drag and drop with a drop zone

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, drag-and-drop, coordinates, custom-renderer

I am trying to implement drag and drop to create a grammatical exercise in which you have to complete the sentence with the right word, dragging the right answer in the right spot (as shown in figure below).
[image]

I tried to achieve that by using custom renderer, creating some extended native views that override the methods to implement their dragging and dropping (like `OnTouchEvent` for Android, and `TouchesBegan`, `TouchesMoved`, `TouchesEnded` for iOS). In both platform I am able to drag the custom native views, but only in iOS I am able to drop them into the specific destination view that I want. In Android it seems to be a conflict with Xamarin Forms view coordinates and the native Android coordinates used in the android custom renderer. Even if I try to "adjust" them, (by manually inserting the coordinates that I want the view to be dropped in) it seems like that the check `if(destinationRect.Contains(myTouchX, myTouchY)` doesn't work proper.

Git repository example here: [Git example](https://github.com/Poli97/DragDropTest)

Does anyone know how to solve that?
Or does anyone know how to implement drag and drop (with a proper dropzone to check) in any other easiest way?

Answer (score 2):

In Android, it provide the `View.StartDrag(ClipData, View+DragShadowBuilder, Object, Int32) Method` method to start a drag and drop operation.

You could check the MS document.

`View.StartDrag(ClipData, View+DragShadowBuilder, Object, Int32) Method`:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/android.views.view.startdrag?view=xamarin-android-sdk-9

`View.StartDragAndDrop(ClipData, View+DragShadowBuilder, Object, Int32) Method`:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/android.views.view.startdraganddrop?view=xamarin-android-sdk-9

Based on my search, this blog would be helpful for this method.
https://pumpingco.de/blog/adding-drag-and-drop-to-your-android-application-with-xamarin/

You could download the source file from the GitHub.
https://github.com/Pumpingcode/Xamarin-DragAndDropDemo

[image]